# Tableau - Using SQL Stored Procedure as an Extract data source

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, tableau-api

I created SQL stored procedure in Tableau as a data source using extract connection. Sample stored procedure below. Then I published the workbook and defined the refresh schedule in tableau server. Will this work? How does Tableau execute/refresh the SQL stored procedure as a data source. I just need to understand the technicalities of it.

What is the alternative way of doing it? I'm avoiding to use the SQL table because I want to be able to update the stored procedure whenever I can. OR will it make a difference if I create a custom SQL in Tableau using the code from the stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROC DBO.MYSP
@Start DATE,
@End DATE

SET @Start = '1/1/2019'
SET @End = '12/31/2999'

SELECT *
FROM MYTABLE WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE MYDATE BETWEEN @Start AND @END

END
GO
```

Comment: Depends on the range on mydate, I would suggest connecting directly to the table.  You could also connect to a view if you want the ability to change things later on (but both these options will affect how your workbook works)

Comment: @cmcau thanks for the reply. The range of the date is dynamic (see above) We are implementing an Extract connection vs live so that we won't stress the server performance. So you are saying it is not advisable to use Stored Procedure even though there's a refresh schedule in the tableau server? Whats the difference using the view vs stored procedure?

Comment: You have uploaded the report to tableau server, so is their any issue with the refresh when extract option is used? what is the status of the instance in tableau server?

Comment: i can only see the update dat and time i have no admin rights.